# Integer Solutions to a system of diophantine equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there any integer solutions $(x,y,z,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_3,c_1,c_2)$ for: $x + y^{b_1}z^{c_1} = y + x^{a_2}z^{c_2}=z+x^{a_3}y^{b_3}$.

Where $x \le y \le z$ The one thing I could tell about this equation is that if you consider $x + y^{b_1}z^{c_1} = y + x^{a_2}z^{c_2}$ since $y - x \le z$ either $c_1$ or $c_2$ must be $0$.

EDIT: $(x,y,z,a_2,a_3,b_1,b_3,c_1,c_2)$ are all positive integers. Also I realized that if $c_1,c_2 = 0$ for the system of equations to be satisfied it is possible when for $(x,y,a,b)$ if $x^a-x = y^b - y$ who's solutions are here:
http://oeis.org/A057896.

Comment: This has the makings of an interesting question, but as it stands permits trivial solutions with $x=y=z$ and $a_2=a_3=b_1=b_3=c_1=c_2$. Also, if negative integers are allowed, permitting $x<0<y<z$, then it is possible that $y-x>z$.

Comment: You're, right let me edit the question so it's only positive integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking first for a simple solution in positive integers with $x\leq y\leq z$, suppose we try $x=1$ and $a_2=a_3=b_1=b_3=c_1=c_2=1$.  The equation then reduces to:

$$1+yz=y+z=z+y$$

where we also require $1\leq y\leq z$. Rearranging:

$$yz-y=z-1$$

$$y(z-1)=z-1$$

Hence $y=1$ and $z$ can be any integer $\geq 1$. Taking $z=2$ as the simplest case that avoids the trivial $x=y=z$ we have the solution:

$$1+1^12^1=1+1^12^1=2+1^11^1=3$$

A necessary condition for $x + y^{b_1}z^{c_1} = y + x^{a_2}z^{c_2}$ with $c_1,c_2\geq 1$ is that $z|(y-x)$. In the above solution this is trivially satisfied since $y-x=0$.

Suppose now we add the additional requirement that $x<y<z$. Then $z\nmid (y-x)$ since $0<y-x<z$. Thus the necessary condition can no longer be satisfied.  So we can conclude that the equation:

$$x + y^{b_1}z^{c_1} = y + x^{a_2}z^{c_2}=z+x^{a_3}y^{b_3}$$

has no solutions in positive integers with $x<y<z$.  Given the equation's symmetry in $x,y,z$, we can also state that it has no solution in positive integers with $x,y,z$ all different.

Comment: What if $(a_2,a_3,b_1,b_3,c_1,c_2)$ are all non negative?

Comment: @Nimish If we require $1<x<y<z$ but with $(a_2,a_3,b_1,b_3,c_1,c_2)$ only required to be non-negative, then solutions are possible, for example: $$2+3^25^0=3+2^35^0=5+2^13^1=11$$

Comment: I've looked into the equations quite a bit, and intuitively it seems that for solutions to exist $c_1$ and $c_2$ have to be zero. I've been able to show that $c_1$ OR $c_2$ have to be zero, but showing that both are zero has eluded me. Is that true, and how would you approach it.